# Adding mongod "where" Clause in java

Tags: java, mongodb

```java
final Object[] columnNames=new String[] {"Room No.","Room Type","Bed Type","Tariff"};
SimpleDateFormat sdf= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
DefaultTableModel dtm=new DefaultTableModel(columnNames,0);
dt1=jDateChooser1.getDate();
dt2=jDateChooser2.getDate();
String strdtver1=(String) sdf.format(jDateChooser1.getDate());
String strdtver2=(String) sdf.format(jDateChooser2.getDate());
long diff=((dt2.getTime()-dt1.getTime()+ONE_HOUR)/(ONE_HOUR*24));
diffday=Long.toString(diff);
daytext.setText(diffday+"  day(s)");

roomtable.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
DefaultTableModel u = (DefaultTableModel) roomtable.getModel();
int n = u.getRowCount();
for (int i = 0;i<n;i++){
    u.removeRow(0);
}
try{
    // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter Mobile Number Correct... ");
    Mongo mongo =new Mongo("127.0.0.1",27017); 
    DB db=mongo.getDB("hotel_management");
    DBCollection collection=db.getCollection("roominfo_info");
    System.out.println("Connected to DB");
    //String day = jComboBox5.getSelectedItem().toString();
    DBCursor cursor = collection.find();
    //DefaultTableModel u = (DefaultTableModel) jTable10.getModel();
    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter Mobile Number Correct... ");
    while(cursor.hasNext()) {
        u.addRow(new Object[]{
                cursor.next().get("Room No"),
                cursor.curr().get("Room Type"),
                cursor.curr().get("Bed Type"),
                cursor.curr().get("Tariff")
        });                 
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println(""+ ex);
}
```

So basically, i have stored date in String strdtver1 and String strdtver2
I have to use a clause like we use in mysql,with where clause, "from" String strdtver1 "to" String strdtver2, so that the room that are not booked in that specific timeline are shown, only i have to do it in MongoDB!
Thank you

Comment: You should have stored as a `Date` type instead of a string. Also your question point to very little familiarity with MongoDB. I would suggest a [basic tutorial on querying](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/) and a look at the [SQL Mapping Chart](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/) where both are from the core documentation. StackOverflow is not the place for tutorial examples.

Comment: I am familiar to mysql but new to MongoDB! Sorry for asking such newbie question here! I'll refer to some documentation for help!
Thank you for your time!